# Redirect user to library after saving InfoPath form

Tags: infopath, custom-form

I've made a form using InfoPath Designer 2013 and published it to a SharePoint Online 2013 form library. Everything works as expected, the data get saved to the library when the user clicks the save button in SharePoint ribbon. But for some reason the user is not redirected to the SharePoint library after that.

Searching about this issue only led me to solutions where the user had to be redirect to a custom url, not the list/library. I checked the form url and the variable &Source is pointing to the library.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: How users reach the info path form?

Comment: Through the library it self. They just click "New item" link.

Comment: In that case the Source Parameter is not set properly. Can you outline how you set the Source parameter?

Comment: That's the thing: I didn't set it. The expected behaviour is to redirect to the library by default. I'll try and see if there's some configuration that I did wrong. Thank you @AmalHashim

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue may be that you are saving from the ribbon and not "Submitting" the form. You mention that you are saving from the ribbon, I am not sure that InfoPath Form Services interprets that as a form submission. Can you test creating a button to "Submit" the form via a "Submit" data connection within the InfoPath form and see if the redirect occurs?

The Source parameter only gets processed by InfoPath Form Services.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms772417(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Occurs in a new form and editing an existing form. The Source parameter is absolute. It's redirecting to the same library where the forms are stored.

Comment: I don't have the .xns right now, but I'll give it a try later. Thanks @CuriousAboutSP

Answer (score 0):

In File < Submit Options < Advanced, is "After Submit" set correctly?